# Pingdom Tools 503 server not available error. Can someone explain the error and possible resolutions to this?

Tags: php, http-status-code-503, pingdom

I am getting below error descriptions when checking the site at pingdom tools. Can someone explain the possible cause behind this error and how to resolve it?

```
Response Headers 503
Server: Apache
Connection: Close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Retry-After: 86400
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Request Headers
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Host: www.dummyname.com
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: 503 is server unavailable. 5xxin general mean, that something is bad on their side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every errors 5xx are server-side, that means there is nothing much you can do for fix it.

If you take a look at the error codes messages you can check this:

> 503 Service Unavailable The server is currently unavailable (because
>   it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a
>   temporary state.[63]

pingdom is a big server, so surely it has several servers working on, the one your computer just used seems down, keep retrying may help

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Hi. I'm getting this from last 4 months both with pingdom and Google page speed insight.

Comment: Did you try opening Devtools in your Chrome or Firefox browser and check the Network tab what your POST or GET request sends, and what it gets back?

Then use postman or any external website to send that request again from another server (not your local host) and see what happens, also you can put your post here and I will check